# Why isn't there a continuously differentiable injection into a lower dimensional space?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

How to show that a continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^m$ can't be a 1-1 when $n>m$? This is an exercise in Spivak's "Calculus on manifolds".

I can solve the problem in the case $m=1$. To see this, note that the result is obvious if the first partial derivative $D_1 f(x)=0$ for all $x$ as then $f$ will be independent of the first variable. Otherwise there exists $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $D_1 f(a)\not=0$. Put $g:A\to \mathbb{R}^n, g(x)=(f(x),x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ (with $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$). Now the Jacobian 
$$ 
g'(x) = \left[
          \begin{array}{cc}
             D_1 f(x) & 0 \\
             0        & I_{n-1}     
          \end{array}
        \right]
$$ 
so that $\text{det}\, g'(a)=D_1 f(a)\not=0$. By the Inverse Function Theorem we have an open set $B\subseteq A$ s.t. $g:B\to g(B)$ is bijective with a differentiable inverse. In particular, $g(B)$ is open.

Pick any $g(b)=(f(b),b_2,\ldots, b_n)\in g(B)$. Since $g(B)$ is open there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that  $(f(b), b_2, \ldots, b_n+\varepsilon) \in g(B)$. Thus we can find $b'\in B$ s.t. $g(b')=(f(b), b_2, \ldots, b_n+\varepsilon)$. By the definition of $g$, $f(b')=f(b)$ with $b'$ and $b$ differing in the last coordinate. Thus $f$ isn't injective.

However, I cannot generalize this argument to higher dimenssions.

Comment: This is exercise 2.37, for more reference see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414426/spivak-calculus-on-manifolds-problem-2-37-b).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $k\leq m$ be the maximum rank of $f'(x)$ when  $x$ runs through $\mathbb R^n$ and $a\in \mathbb R^n$ be a point where the maximum is attained: $rank(f'(a))=k$.
We will have  $rank(f'(u))=k$ for all $u$ in some open neighbourhood  $U$ of $a$ [obtained by  choosing a non-zero $k\times k$ minor of $f'(a)$].
The constant rank theorem will then assure us that locally near $a$ the map $f$ looks like $  (x_1,...,x_n) \mapsto  (x_1,...,x_k,0,...,0)$ and is thus not injective since $n\gt k$ (because $n\gt m\geq k$)

**Edit**
[Here](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/%7EPierre-Yves.Gaillard/DIVERS/Constant-rank-theorem/constant-rank-theorem-110320a.pdf) is a 13-line proof of the constant rank theorem, written by a high-quality contributor to this site: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard

Comment: Thx for the answer I'm not really familiar with the constant rank theorem. The book doesn't mention it either so I wait if someone comes up with a more elementary solution.

Comment: Dear KPK, I'll be very happy if someone else gives a solution more to your taste. But I suspect that it would amount to reproving the constant rank theorem in a special case.  By the way, that's exactly what you did for $m=1$! Indeed (in your notation)   $(f\circ g^{-1})(f(x),x_2,...,x_n)=f(x)$ can be rewritten as $(f\circ g^{-1})(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)=y_1$. In other words,  up to the coordinate change effected by your ingeniously constructed $g$, the map $f$ is simply projection on the first factor.

Comment: Perhaps that's the idea of the whole exercise. In the book this problem comes right after the Inverse Function Theorem. There's an a)-part about the case $n=2$, $m=1$ (construction of $g$ is given as a hint) and b)-part asks the general result. I wonder what the precise statetements of the constant rank theorem might be and whether it would be difficult to prove in this special case?

Comment: Dear KPK, I have added (in an Edit to my answer) a link to an incredibly short proof of the constant rank theorem. I think it would be a worthwhile investment to read the proof or at least to remember the precise statement.

Comment: Thank you for the link as well as for all the other help. I red the proof altough I'm not 100 percent sure if I understood all the details on first reading; have to look that again some other day:) Anyway, I believe I can now at least answer to my original question. Somehow the idea of arguing using the rank had escaped me.

Comment: [This link](http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~gaillapy/DIVERS/Constant-rank-theorem/constant-rank-theorem-110320a.pdf) in the answer is now broken.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another answer which probably uses machinery you don't have, but has the advantage of working in the topological category.

First, recall the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem):

> If $g:S^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, then there is a point $p \in S^n$ such that $g(p) = g(-p)$.

In particular, there are no continuous injective maps from $S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous and injective.  Let $i:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be the canonical inclusion.

Then $i\circ f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is continuous.  Now, restricting $i\circ f$ to $S^{n-1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ gives a map $i\circ f|_{S^{n-1}}:S^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

By Borsuk-Ulam, this new map cannot be injective.  Since $i$ is injective, this means $f$ cannot be injective either.

Comment: Borsuk Ulam is true for $n\ge 2$ right?

Comment: @Mex:  It's true for $n\geq 0$.

Comment: could you help me to solve this one with out borsuk ulam? show $C^{\infty}$ function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can not be injective?

Comment: @Mex:  In the $C^\infty$ case, I'd suggest Georges's proof above mine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a full solution for the general case, myself, but I can boil it down to a simpler problem which I feel may have a more elementary solution.

Firstly, I believe you miscalculated the top row of $g'$.
In the $m=1$ case, it comes out to:

$$
  g'(x)
  =
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c|ccc}
      D_1 f(x) & D_2 f(x) & \dots & D_n f(x) \\ \hline
      0 & & I_{n-1} & \\
    \end{array}
  \right]
$$

The determinant still comes out to be $\det(g'(x)) = D_1 f(x)$.

In the general case, $g'$ becomes

$$
  g'(x)
  =
  \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
      D_1 f^1(x) & \dots & D_m f^1(x) & D_{m+1} f^1(x) & \dots & D_n f^1(x) \\
      \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      D_1 f^m(x) & \dots & D_m f^m(x) & D_{m+1} f^m(x) & \dots & D_n f^m(x) \\ \hline
      & 0 & & & I_{n-m} & \\
    \end{array}
  \right]
$$

The determinant then becomes

$$
  \det(g'(x))
  =
  \left|
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      D_1 f^1(x) & \dots & D_m f^1(x) \\
      \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      D_1 f^m(x) & \dots & D_m f^m(x) \\
    \end{array}
  \right|
$$

As before, this determinant cannot be nonzero anywhere, or else you can apply the inverse function theorem again, to show that $f$ is not 1-1. Therefore it remains to be shown that *if this determinant is zero everywhere, $f$ cannot be 1-1.*
It seems intuitively clear to me that that $(f^1, \dots, f^m)$ should fail to be 1-1, and therefore so will $f$, but I'm having difficulties showing it using the earlier results from Spivak.

To be clear, I claim that the general case boils down to: if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously differentiable and satisfies $\det(f'(x)) = 0$ for all $x$, then $f$ is not 1-1.

Comment: If we are able to show that $f^1,...,f^m$ all fail to be 1-1, what is the argument we can use to show that $f$ is not 1-1?  These component functions are continuously differentiable maps from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$, so we can apply the OP's work above.

Comment: Not sure. Maybe consider the "level curves" (level surfaces?) of the f^i, in some not ill-chosen point, and then show that they intersect in more than one point? (Of course, this is just a re-statement of your question.)

Comment: Hmm okay.  There are definitely counterexamples for $m > n$.  I'll think about it.