# If $\operatorname{dim} M > \operatorname{dim} N$, is there an injective smooth map $M\to N$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $m>n$ and suppose $M$ is a smooth $m$-manifold, $N$ is a smooth $n$-manifold.

Can there be an injective smooth map $f:M\to N$?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Considering the problem locally, this requires an injective smooth map $\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: True, but why does no such smooth map exist? That's not obvious.

Comment: I've been thinking about it since you posted it. I see Zhen Lin's comment concurs with my thoughts...

Comment: @BrunoStonek Yes, it's not as obvious as it seems and the full answer is best given using homology. At least the case $n=1$ is simple: Removing a single point from $\mathbb R^m$ leaves the space connected, hence also the image is connected, but that can't be if it misses an interior point.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *no*, and in fact there cannot even be an injective *continuous* map $M\to N$.

As noted by Hagen von Eitzen, we look at the map locally, so that it suffices to show that there is no continuous injection $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$. This can be done using the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, as done by Jason DeVito in his answer to [Why isn't there a continuously differentiable injection into a lower dimensional space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159446/why-isnt-there-a-continuously-differentiable-injection-into-a-lower-dimensional).