# Show $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $n>m$ can't be 1-1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Problem 2-37 on p. 39 of Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* asks

> - Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Show that $f$ is *not* 1-1. (Hint: If, for
>     example, $D_1f(x,y) \neq 0$ for all $(x,y)$ in some open set $A$,
>     consider $g: A \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $g(x,y)=(f(x,y),y)$.)
> - Generalize this result to the case of a continuously differentiable    function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m<n$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159446/why-isnt-there-a-continuously-differentiable-injection-into-a-lower-dimensional) previous question has the same question I do: how does he want us to do the second part? One response there suggests just proving the constant-rank theorem. I can't imagine that is what he has in mind, since he states and proves that theorem in the next section.

[This](http://jianfeishen.weebly.com/uploads/4/7/2/6/4726705/calculus_on_manifolds.pdf#page=43) is a suggested solution to the second part, but I think it is erroneous. (It assumes that if vector-valued $f$ is 1-1, then at some $x$ there is some component $f^i$ that is both 1-1 near  $x$ and has nonzero gradient at $x$. I don't see why this would be true *a priori*. I'm trying to think of a counterexample when $n \leq m$.)

Comment: If you do go down the constant rank route, this may help http://math.stackexchange.com/a/901671/27978.

Comment: By the Open Domain Principle, each continuous injective map $f:U→\Bbb R^n$  defined on an open subset $U\subset \Bbb R^ n$  is an open topological embedding. But this seems to be much powerful tool than you use.